# Why WifiInfo.getRssi() always return -200?

Tags: android, wifi

I made an aplication that shows actual wifi conection information.

```
      cont = act.getApplicationContext();
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)cont.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  display.setText(cadena + "\n Rssi:" + wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi() 
    + "\n BSSID: " +
    wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID()
    + "\n wifiState: " +
    wifiManager.getWifiState()
    + "\n SSID: " +
    wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID()
    + "\n LinkSpeed: " +
    wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed()
    + "\n NetworkId: " +
    wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId());
```

The app shows the values correctly exept for the Rssi, i shows -200, no matter if i'm conected to a wifi net or not.

I don´t have a phone to test it, but i have a pc with Android for pc.

The Android SDK emulator doesn't conect via wifi but  getRssi() still return -200.

Is -200 some kind of "error value"?

Answer (score 0):

I think so - at least it can be found in the Android source code, see here (line 1548):
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread-release/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiStateTracker.java#1548

It's not a defined constant if you wanted to know that.

I suggest you should not use the emulator for WiFi-related testing. Maybe you can borrow a real Android device somewhere. Or just go ahead and buy one - the new Android devices really are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that time i couldn't do anything with this. I always got -200 and couldn't understand what that means. But i used ScanResult to do what i needed.

Now that i have a real Phone i decided to try this once more and it works. So it's a problem of the emulator and the x86 android.

Thanks for the answer! i'm sorry i didn't thanks before

Comment: -200 represents miniml level 4 Wifi...levels above -30 are usful though